# How to find and delete files using the description in Command Prompt

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, cmd.exe

There is a virus that duplicates itself.

The names of the exe files are all random, but all of the applications have 1 common thing. The description of the application is always 'minecraft' (Some other kid came and put it on the computer).

So my question is: How can I find all exe files with a description of 'minecraft'.

This is a testing computer and the ram is low, I don't want to put any antivirus or scanners.

While answering this don't think about the virus and spreading, I just need a way (if possible) to search files using their description.

Comment: I suggest to use an Antivirus Software booted from an USB-Stick. While Windows is running and the malware still in RAM, scanning the disk may be counterproductive.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using PowerShell. As an example you can display all the executable files with their descriptions with this command:

```
Get-ChildItem <your-path>\*.exe -Recurse | select Name, 
@{label="Description";expression={$_.VersionInfo.FileDescription}}
```

The part after the pipe symbol pulls out the name and the description. You can adapt this to search for a particular description with a WHERE moderator:

```
Get-ChildItem <your-path>\*.exe -recurse | select Name, 
@{label="Description";expression={$_.VersionInfo.FileDescription}} | where 
Description -eq 'minecraft'
```

If you are having trouble with the WHERE clause, try -like 'mine*' or similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
CD \
FORFILES /S /M *minecraft* /C "cmd /c echo @path"
```

This returns a list of al the filenames which contain 'minecraft' in their filename

more info on [FORFILES](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles)

EDIT: Description was needed, someone did not think that was needed before Windows, and that's why it is not available through any 'standard' command (and also not using WMIC.EXE)

Reference: [File Description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32861201/print-file-descriptions-from-all-files-in-a-folder-wmic-command)

```
@if (@this==@isBatch) @then 
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    call :listFilesProperties "d:\temp"
    goto :eof

:listFilesProperties folder    
    cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~f0" "%~f1"
    goto :eof

@end  
var folderNameSpace = WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application").NameSpace(WScript.Arguments.Item(0));

    for (
        var fileEnum = new Enumerator(folderNameSpace.Items());
        !fileEnum.atEnd();
        fileEnum.moveNext()
    ){
        var fileName = fileEnum.item();
        var description = folderNameSpace.GetDetailsOf(fileName, 34);
        WScript.Echo( fileName + '|'  + description);
    };
```

sample output:

```
sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3280000.zip|
SQLite.Interop.dll|System.Data.SQLite Interop Assembly
sqlite3.def|
sqlite3.dll|SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine.
sqlite3.exe|SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine.
sqlite3_analyzer.exe|
```

Comment: Thank you for this reply but this solution does not use the description